# Dynamic loading using Tabs module and CCK Fieldgroup tabs

Tags: 6, routes

I am currently using the Tabs and CCK Fieldgroup Tabs modules to display views in a tabbed format on nodes of a custom type. However, pages take a long time to load because the content in every tab is loaded at once. I want to dynamically load each tab only when it is clicked. How can I accomplish this? For example, look at the first node on [this page](http://www.glumbo.com/deals/newegg.com-deals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example page uses [Quick Tabs module](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs).

> I want to dynamically load each tab
>   only when it is clicked. How can I
>   accomplish this?

Quick Tabs gives the option to dynamically load content with ajax. [Here is demonstration linked to by the Quick Tabs project page.](http://observers.gohernandez.com/election/results/2005/kabul) To get that solution please read the [Quick Tabs documentation.](http://drupal.org/node/679116)

Yes, the example you give uses the Quick Tabs module. It says so in the markup. `class="clear-block quicktabs_tabs quicktabs-style-excel ui-tabs-nav tabs primary"`

Comment: No I use Quick Tabs on my homepage but not that page. Quick Tabs has the dynamic loading I want but I need it on this page also